# Ajax Form Within Magento Onepage Checkout Help

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, ajax

I am trying to put an Ajax form within the checkout process of Magento. I am having a slight issue though.

I have the form working as a sidebar on my sight, but I am having a conflict with one of the scripts that I found for my Ajax form. When I use it on the checkout page the onepage doesn't load like at all, but as soon as I remove it, it loads, but my form no longer changes like it should.

The working form can be seen here: https://www.therange702.com/gun-store.html

This is the script code that causes the conflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
```

Whats inside that can be seen here -> https://www.therange702.com/js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js

Sorry for the linking, the code in that is too big to put in here. I know this is the issue, cause if I remove the `<Script>` tag then it loads, but like i said my form no longer changes to the other part of it. I even removed the tag from the working form in the sidebar and it cause it to not work anymore.

I know it is a very old file, but I am new to ajax and I found a tutorial that I followed and used the source files that were provided. If you have suggestions for using a new file I am open to that too, maybe one that is actually understandable.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'jquery-1.2.6.pack.js'?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and prototype conflict on the $ variable. Append jQuery.noConflict(); to the jquery-1.2.6.pack.js file and don't use $ but jQuery in your other jQuery scripts.

You can use the $ in your functions like this:

```
var something = (function($) {
    $('#id'); // <-- jQuery object
} (jQuery));

var else = $('id'); <-- prototype object
```

I don't know if this will solve your whole problem, but it will get you one step closer to the solution. Keep us posted on what happens next.